# Most middleware (like compress) is no longer bundled with .. ERROR

Tags: node.js, init

Please, help me How can i solve this problem?

```
Starting static webserver: /home/ubuntu/node/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89
      throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundle
            ^
Error: Most middleware (like cookieParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (/home/ubuntu/node/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node/static-app.js:26:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:124:16)
    at node.js:811:3
```

Comment: Did you check the linked resource and what it says about compress?

Answer (score 3):

You have updated your express to 4.0, but it doesn't have all the middleware included now, so you have to install them manually.

See the [Moving to Express 4.0 guide](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html)

> Express 4 no longer depends on Connect, and removes all the built-in middleware from its core, except express.static. This means Express is now an independent routing and middleware web framework, and Express versioning and releases are not affected by middleware updates.
>
> With the built-in middleware gone, you must explicitly add all the middleware required to run your app. Simply follow these steps:
>
> Install the module: *npm install --save*
>
> In your app, require the module: *require('module-name');*
>
> Use the module according to its documentation: *app.use( ... );*