# Nodejs doesn't recognize body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Im trying to develop a nodejs app, however when I try to use the body parser the following error shows up:

"Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware."

Here's my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/views'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());

//Start server
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8000, function(request,     response){
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('views/htmls/main.html');
})
app.get('/nuevo', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('views/htmls/nuevo.html');
})
app.post('/', function(req,res){
res.send('Name"' + req.body.title + '".');
})
});
console.log('Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000');
```

The error shows up when I add the line:
   app.use(express.bodyParser());

If I comment it, I get no error.

I already tried:
     npm install body-parser
and
    npm install -g body-parser

and still no fix.

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most middleware (like compress) is no longer bundled with .. ERROR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960186/most-middleware-like-compress-is-no-longer-bundled-with-error)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

The link you posted explains that express no longer ships with bodyParser, you have required it correctly but you have tried to reference it as express.bodyParser() rather than just bodyParser().

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all open your console and write :

```
npm init
```

It will ask about some stuff(just keep them if you want or insert some random data)
next try

```
npm install body-parser
```

PS : add the option `--save` if you want to To add an entry to your package.json's dependencies

For further details please [visit the official npm website and read this article](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json) and [body parse page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

PS : don't forget to add `var myParser = require("body-parser");`
to your code so node JS will include the library.